# Mutiple @ConfigurationProperties don't work. Just load one

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a batch with **spring-boot-starter-batch 2.7.13**, the same thing happens with version **2.7.1**, so I don't think it's a version problem. JDK1.8.

I have created two classes to load properties from properties files but defined by environment (int, pre, pro) the settings are all defined in main, and in the corresponding classes.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.batch"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { 
                                     DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                                     DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
                                     HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties ({AppProp.class , ClientProp.class})
public class BatchApplication implements CommandLineRunner {...}
```

The ClientProp class is defined as follows

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ocr", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
    public class ClientProp {
    private Map<String, String> ws;
    public Map<String, String> getWS() {
    return ws;
    }
    public void setWS(Map<String, String> ws) {
    this.ws = ws;
    }
    }
```

If I put a breakpoint in the setter it stops, which doesn't happen in the other class, it doesn't stop in any of the setters.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pbc", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
public class AppProp {
private Map<String, String> job;
private Map<String, String> extension;
private Map<String, String> repository;
...getters/setters
}
```

I don't understand what the charging problem is.
In the debug traces, you can see how spring initializes the beans.

```
2023-06-28 13:28:04.480 DEBUG 13076 --- [ main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'pbc-com.batch.jobs.config.AppProp'
2023-06-28 13:28:04.502 DEBUG 13076 --- [ main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ocr-com.batch.jobs.config.ClientProp'
```

The propertie file by environment is application-*int*.properties

```
pbc.extension.types=
pbc.repository.running=
pbc.repository.root.path=
pbc.repository.inbound=
pbc.repository.in-progress=
pbc.repository.error=
pbc.repository.processed=
pbc.repository.treated.file=

pbc.job.thread.pool.size=

pbc.job.commit.limit=

pbc.job.thread.limit=

ocr.ws.endpoint=
ocr.ws.app.user=
ocr.ws.app.password=
ocr.ws.app.project=
ocr.ws.app.schedule.process=
ocr.ws.app.try.process=

ocr.manager.endpoint.base=
ocr.manager.version.api=
ocr.manager.analisis.api=
ocr.manager.url.notification=
ocr.manager.codigo.cliente=
```

What can be wrong?
Thanks

I don't understand the reason but according to the local configuration I have the files application-dev.properties, application-int.propeties, etc. and it only loads the properties if i select in dev environment but if i select int it doesn't work.
What is the reason?

Could the problem be that a dependency has a properties file with the same name and only loads the internal as seen in the traces?
If so, how can you override those properties or exclude them and put them in the main application's property? See the trace **2023-06-30 11:18:15.952 DEBUG 10060**

```
2023-06-30 11:18:15.097  INFO   --- [           main] c.batch.RidocrBatchApplication  : Profile: int
2023-06-30 11:18:15.707 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'info.app.build.date' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
2023-06-30 11:18:15.708 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'application.version' in PropertySource 'version' with value of type String
2023-06-30 11:18:15.708 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring-boot.version' in PropertySource 'version' with value of type String

2023-06-30 11:18:15.864 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.application.name' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
2023-06-30 11:18:15.873  INFO 10060 --- [           main] c.batch.RidocrBatchApplication  : Starting RidocrBatchApplication on zaesvdicnt-203 with PID 10060 (******\ridocr-batch\target\classes started by eit6529 in ******\ridocr-batch)
2023-06-30 11:18:15.874  INFO 10060 --- [           main] c.batch.RidocrBatchApplication  : The following profiles are active: int
2023-06-30 11:18:15.874 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.batch.RidocrBatchApplication
2023-06-30 11:18:15.951 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Activated activeProfiles int
2023-06-30 11:18:15.952 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:/******/ridocr-batch/target/classes/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
2023-06-30 11:18:15.952 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'jar:file:/******/ocr-client/0.0.18/ocr-client-0.0.18.jar!/application-int.properties' (classpath:/application-int.properties) for profile int
2023-06-30 11:18:15.953 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@ac4250
2023-06-30 11:18:15.987 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.017 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.135 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [******\ridocr-batch\target\classes\ridocr\batch\jobs\config\BatchConfig.class]
2023-06-30 11:18:16.139 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [******\ridocr-batch\target\classes\ridocr\batch\jobs\config\FilenetConnectionConfig.class]
2023-06-30 11:18:16.141 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [******\ridocr-batch\target\classes\ridocr\batch\jobs\config\OCRConfig.class]
2023-06-30 11:18:16.144 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [******\ridocr-batch\target\classes\ridocr\batch\jobs\config\RidOcrProperties.class]
2023-06-30 11:18:16.151 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [******\ridocr-batch\target\classes\ridocr\batch\jobs\process\JobRIDOCRProcess.class]
2023-06-30 11:18:16.170 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: file [******\ridocr-batch\target\classes\ridocr\batch\jobs\utils\ProcessCount.class]
2023-06-30 11:18:16.174 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/******/ocr-client/0.0.18/ocr-client-0.0.18.jar!/ocr/client/config/ConfigClient.class]
2023-06-30 11:18:16.432 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.535 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.batch.job.enabled' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
2023-06-30 11:18:16.711 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.718 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'stepScope'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.719 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jobScope'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.720 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.721 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.723 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.724 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.729 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.730 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.733 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.738 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.745 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Autowiring by type from bean name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' via factory method to bean named 'environment'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.760 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
2023-06-30 11:18:16.794 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ridocrBatchApplication'
2023-06-30 11:18:17.003 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ridOcrProperties'
2023-06-30 11:18:17.005 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ridocr-com.batch.jobs.config.AppCfgProp'
2023-06-30 11:18:17.015 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2023-06-30 11:18:17.016 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration'
2023-06-30 11:18:17.047 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionAttributeSource'
2023-06-30 11:18:17.054 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionInterceptor'
2023-06-30 11:18:17.066 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ocr-com.batch.jobs.config.OcrClientProp'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.390 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'batchConfig'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.395  WARN 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.a.DefaultBatchConfigurer       : No datasource was provided...using a Map based JobRepository
2023-06-30 11:18:23.396  WARN 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.a.DefaultBatchConfigurer       : No transaction manager was provided, using a ResourcelessTransactionManager
2023-06-30 11:18:23.410 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] .t.i.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method [*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
2023-06-30 11:18:23.411 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] .t.i.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method [create*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE]
2023-06-30 11:18:23.412 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] .t.i.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method [getLastJobExecution*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE]
2023-06-30 11:18:23.439  INFO 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2023-06-30 11:18:23.441 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'OCRConfig'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.526 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jobRIDOCRProcess'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.528 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'processCount'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.533 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jobBuilders'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.534 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.551 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jobRepository'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.562 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'stepBuilders'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.563 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
2023-06-30 11:18:23.569 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jobTaskExecutorMultiThreaded'
2023-06-30 11:18:25.195  WARN 10060 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRIDOCRProcess': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobTaskExecutorMultiThreaded'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobTaskExecutorMultiThreaded' defined in class path resource [ridocr/batch/jobs/config/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor]: Factory method 'jobTaskExecutorMultiThreaded' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2023-06-30 11:18:25.201 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] .c.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: .....
2023-06-30 11:18:25.231 DEBUG 10060 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
```

Comment: Please share more details: 1. packages of the classes 2. content of properties files 3. application log at startup.

Comment: Add the `application.properties` you ar eusing.

Comment: @Mar-Z the classes are in the same package "com.batch.jobs.config."

Comment: Are both classes annotated with @Configuration?

Comment: `getWS` doesn't match the property `ws`. Your getter/setter should be `getWs`

Comment: @M.Deinum this work perfectly the other class no

Comment: @Mar-Z
No, just as it is in the example code and it is not necessary to define

Comment: No it doesn't as stated `getWS` doesn't match the field/property `ws`. Either change your config to `opc.WS` or change your getter/setter. This is how properties work in Java (you might want to read the Java Bean specification for that).

Comment: @M.Deinum I can't change properties and the getter/setter was made with eclipse automatically.

Comment: Then Eclipse is borked. Change the getter/setter else it will not bind/match.

Comment: Please share application logs on startup with Spring active profile `int`

Answer (score 0):

> how can you override those properties

As you are using the same properties file name as the external JAR on the classpath you should let Spring load you properties first. You can do it by putting your file either in:

1. The current directory
2. The `config`/ subdirectory in the current directory
3. Immediate child directories of the `config/` subdirectory

Based on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific

Comment: The properties files are in the resources folder in both the external jar and the client app. You should replace or charge it first

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Having the same property file name is a valid situation. However **only the first file** found by Spring will be loaded. That's why you should put your file in the directory listed in the answer. Putting it on the classpath is not enough because the other one will be found first.